# XML sort by tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, sorting

I am trying to convert this XML tree

```
<IN1>
    <IN1.1>
        <IN1.1.1>1</IN1.1.1>
    </IN1.1>
    <IN1.17>
        <IN1.17.1>1</IN1.17.1>
    </IN1.17>
    <IN1.47>
        <IN1.47.1>C</IN1.47.1>
    </IN1.47>
    <IN1.3>
        <IN1.3.1>paycode</IN1.3.1>
    </IN1.3>
</IN1>
```

into this

```
<IN1>
    <IN1.1>
        <IN1.1.1>1</IN1.1.1>
    </IN1.1>
    <IN1.3>
        <IN1.3.1>paycode</IN1.3.1>
    </IN1.3>
    <IN1.17>
        <IN1.17.1>1</IN1.17.1>
    </IN1.17>
    <IN1.47>
        <IN1.47.1>C</IN1.47.1>
    </IN1.47>
</IN1>
```

My current code is

```
for each (field in msg['IN1'].children()) 
{
    fields.push(field.toString());
}
fields.sort();
```

This sorts the last two elements but then re-arranges the first two. What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: What is the sorting criteria?

Comment: you shouldn't really be using "for each in" blocks see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Comment: I suggest you to use a javascript library (like JQuery) or a framework (like ExtJS): they have a easy-to-use and powerful XML parser.

Comment: For the sorting criteria the order should be <IN1.1><IN1.3><IN1.17><IN1.47> instead of <IN1.1><IN1.17><IN1.47><IN1.3> and this must be done without external libraries or frameworks

Comment: @adriang, so, that means you are using jQuery, right?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find some luck by using the jQuery [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) plugin. You can sort DOM elements based on numerical/alphabetical parameters.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT was created to transform XML from one form to another ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqqaq/6/)):

```
var xml = "<IN1><IN1.1><IN1.1.1>1</IN1.1.1></IN1.1><IN1.17><IN1.17.1>1</IN1.17.1></IN1.17><IN1.47><IN1.47.1>C</IN1.47.1></IN1.47><IN1.3><IN1.3.1>paycode</IN1.3.1></IN1.3></IN1>";
var xsl = "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"><xsl:template match=\"IN1\"><IN1><xsl:apply-templates select=\"*\"><xsl:sort select=\"substring-after(name(), 'IN1.')\" data-type=\"number\"/></xsl:apply-templates></IN1></xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"*\"><xsl:copy-of select=\".\"/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var domToBeTransformed = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
var xslt = parser.parseFromString(xsl, "text/xml");
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(xslt);
var newDocument = processor.transformToDocument(domToBeTransformed);
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var newDocumentXml = serializer.serializeToString(newDocument);
alert(newDocumentXml);
```

The above code works in Chrome and Firefox; the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqqaq/6/) has an implementation for IE. The trick with IE is its dependence on Active X. It's all installed with IE, though, so really, no "external" libraries were used.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1) Write a recursive algorithm that sorts each node in the tree.

For each child:

2) Gather all the children under the element into a JavaScript array.
3) Sort the array based on custom criteria.
4) Iterate the array, adding the children to the parent in sorted order.
<sup>Note: re-adding a child into the DOM automatically removes it from its previous location.</sup>

If you need additional help with any of these parts, feel free to clarify.